# Datatables not rendering on my table in MVC project

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I want to improve the look and feel of my tables and jQuery datatables looks great for doing that but I can not work out why it is not rendering on my table. I have registered the plugin correctly on my bundle config. Followed the tutorial and ensured everything was in correct place, but no effect.

Here is my generated code from browser.
I have put an alert in the JavaScript which calls `dataTable()`, this is being called.

the head and body of document are in a different file `_layout.cshtml` to my index page which is where my table is. Not that this should effect anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>

        <script src="/Content/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/demo_table.css"></script>

        <script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>
                       <a class="site-title" href="/">
                       <img src="../../Content/Images/TrakMan_white240.png" ,alt="sort",    style="border-style:none"/></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        Hello, <a class="username" href="/SGAccount/Manage" title="Manage">simon</a>!
                        <form action="/SGAccount/LogOff" id="logoutForm" method="post">
                            <input     name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"   value="qouuJJI98XkICybk1UEozbZayptmhHh1zgsHQfTcu9kz6PJrZ_TObkO8Yhkkqv06jtklWRKOSAhUs3w1Bqm58Y-cy7Q8I5dl_loxDuU6AqReCRtWRHg7p4ipeTVKzNzGG50b7D-x3562Hj2q2In_m-LctFmsLIQ1qpM_iYv0MSQ1"   />
                            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log    off</a>
                        </form>    
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <li><a href="/SGAccount/ChangePassword">Change Password</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/Welcome">Servers</a></li>  
                            <li><a href="/SecurityGuard">Security Guard</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Connection">Connections</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        var el = doucument.getElementByName("customerIndex")
                        el.dataTable({ "sScrolly": "200px", "bPaginate": false });
                    });
                </script>


                <h2>Customers</h2>

                <p>
                    <a class="createButton" href="/Customer/Create">Create New</a>
                </p>

                <table id="customerIndex" class="display">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Column 1</th>
                        <th>Column 2</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                        <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                        <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u post what error you are getting on console.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dataTable'

Comment: Check ref to your dataTable.js

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems:
Your code says "var el = doucument..." but that should be "document".

Also you are using "getElementByName" when your table doesn't have the name attribute set, just the ID set.

But why not use the built in jQuery function to select by ID:

```
$('#customerIndex').dataTable({ "sScrolly": "200px", "bPaginate": false });
```

Answer (score 0):

you load two different jquery version:

```
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.js"></script> // in the header
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script> // in the body
```

another small correction:

```
<script src="/Content/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/demo_table.css"></script>
// should be
<link href="/Content/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

maybe this will correct your error

**Edit**:
change

```
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var el = doucument.getElementByName("customerIndex")
                    el.dataTable({ "sScrolly": "200px", "bPaginate": false });
                });
```

to

```
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#customerIndex").dataTable({ "sScrolly": "200px", "bPaginate": false });
                });
```

Comment: I have removed the extra jquery call, and changed css to correct link, yet still saying object has no Object [object Object] has no method 'dataTable'.

Comment: see edit for more changes (the `dataTable` method only works on jQuery objects)

Comment: i tried var el = doucument.getElementByName("customerIndex") this way as thought mite have been an issue here, I have changed it back to suggested.

Answer (score 0):

had an extra script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js"
at bottom of page.....